# What is the minimum price of an option, given no information about Greeks?

Tags: options, option-pricing, pricing

I was asked this interview questions for an analyst level structuring role and it has been bothering me since I can't figure it out:

*Assuming the price of an equity is 100, what is the minimum price to quote a 150 strike European call option to guarantee you make no losses?*

- You have not information about Greeks;
- You cannot reinvest cash at the risk free rate;
- You only have access to hedging in the spot market.

Comment: Assuming that they wanted to say we can only buy/sell the equity not really knowing how much of it we should own at a certain time the answer is I think that we should hedge that option by buying one stock at 100 and hold it to the end. This guarantees no losses and leads to an option price of 100. Seems like a weird question for a structuring role. Better to test if a candidate knows the basics.